# Ipython on AWS with Spark 1.61

Tags: amazon-web-services, ipython, pyspark, emr

I'm trying to run Ipython on my AWS EMR Spark cluster with Spark 1.6.1. This [guide](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/TxX4BY5T1PQ7BQ/Using-IPython-Notebook-to-Analyze-Data-with-Amazon-EMR#postCommentsTxX4BY5T1PQ7BQ) is an excellent one, but only seems to work with spark 1.3.1. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging, I found out the answer myself. I went through a few steps:

1. Launch an AWS EMR cluster with spark
2. pip install jupyter
3. Generate a jupyter notebook config file: `jupyter notebook --generate-config`
4. Modify that config file to include:
   `c.Notebook.ip = '*'`
   `c.Notebook.open_browser=False`
5. launch the notebook with the iptyhon options: `IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook" pyspark`
6. Set up an SSH Tunnel to the master node following these [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel-local.html)
7. go to localhost:

And that's it!